# Why is DefaultExecutor creating 2 threads for calling the command "php file.php"

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons

I'm using DefaultExecutor of apache-commons-exec to execute a php but when I see the profile I see that the the last line, the execute function is creating 2 parallel threads for call the process synchronous. Why?

```
CommandLine command = new CommandLine("php");
command.addArgument("file.php");

DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();

PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(null, null);
exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

int execute = exec.execute(command);
```

The problem is that I call N threads with a loop calling the *exec.execute(command);*, so if I use 3 threads, every time the execute is being called the APP is creating 6 new threads that dies when the *exec.execute(command);* finishes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVNEI.jpg

Answer (score 1):

i'm not familiar with the library in question, but generally in java when you are executing a separate process, you need extra threads to correctly handle the standard output/error (otherwise the process may block).  i would guess those are the extra threads you are seeing (details on handling process execing [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)).